# Lyx2.1 - New Empty Float Definition Appeared for Some Reason (cannot compile anymore)

Tags: floats, lyx, compiling

I have used LyX to write my dissertation, and for the most part, it has worked quite well.  I am baffled by the current compilation error, however.  After adding a couple floats, I now get the following errors:

```
! Package float Error: Unknown float style `' .

See the float package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.49 \floatstyle{}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

\@float@every@=\toks27
\c@=\count116
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \spacefactor 
l.56 \usepackage
                {url}
A one-character control sequence belongs after a ` mark.
So I'm essentially inserting \0 here.

! Improper \spacefactor.
<recently read> \spacefactor 

l.56 \usepackage
                {url}
You can refer to \spacefactor only in horizontal mode;
you can refer to \prevdepth only in vertical mode; and
neither of these is meaningful inside \write. So
I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.56 \usepackage
                {url}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.56 \usepackage
                {url}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.56 \usepackage
                {url}
```

I first tried to remove the new floats, but that made no difference.  I then tried compiling an older commit, and that worked just fine.  When I compare `tex` exports of both versions, however, I see that an empty float construct has been appended to the user-defined float definitions:

```
\floatstyle{}
\newfloat{}{}{}
\providecommand{\name}{}
\floatname{}{\protect\name}
```

Why would this occur if I have not attempted to define a new float?  How should I stop it from occurring?

**EDIT:** If I delete the new float definition, I can get a `tex` export to compile, but the layout is messed up in some places and all of my references are broken.

**UPDATE:**  Pursuant to the comments, here is the front matter from the `tex` documents.  First, the old document (which compiles just fine):

```
% LyX 2.1.4dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[oneside,english,titlepage]{authesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[unicode=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Special footnote code from the package 'stblftnt.sty'
%% Author: Robin Fairbairns -- Last revised Dec 13 1996
\let\SF@@footnote\footnote
\def\footnote{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\SF@@footnote
  \else
    \expandafter\SF@gobble@opt
  \fi
}
\expandafter\def\csname SF@gobble@opt \endcsname{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \SF@gobble@twobracket
  \@gobble
}
\edef\SF@gobble@opt{\noexpand\protect
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname SF@gobble@opt \endcsname}
\def\SF@gobble@twobracket[#1]#2{}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{model}{tbp}{lol}
\providecommand{\modelname}{Model}
\floatname{model}{\protect\modelname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{DOES ONE SIZE FIT ALL?\\
\emph{AN ANALYSIS OF}\\
\emph{TAX AND EXPENDITURE LIMITATIONS}\\
\emph{IN COLORADO}}
```

And now, the new, problematic document:

```
%% LyX 2.1.4dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[oneside,english,titlepage]{authesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[unicode=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Special footnote code from the package 'stblftnt.sty'
%% Author: Robin Fairbairns -- Last revised Dec 13 1996
\let\SF@@footnote\footnote
\def\footnote{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\SF@@footnote
  \else
    \expandafter\SF@gobble@opt
  \fi
}
\expandafter\def\csname SF@gobble@opt \endcsname{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \SF@gobble@twobracket
  \@gobble
}
\edef\SF@gobble@opt{\noexpand\protect
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname SF@gobble@opt \endcsname}
\def\SF@gobble@twobracket[#1]#2{}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{model}{tbp}{lol}
\providecommand{\modelname}{Model}
\floatname{model}{\protect\modelname}
\floatstyle{}
\newfloat{}{}{}
\providecommand{\name}{}
\floatname{}{\protect\name}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{DOES ONE SIZE FIT ALL?\\
\emph{AN ANALYSIS OF}\\
\emph{TAX AND EXPENDITURE LIMITATIONS}\\
\emph{IN COLORADO}}
```

Comment: Imho this is question which should better go to the lyx developers.

Comment: If it's in the user-defined area, then it should be in the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: It's not added to the preamble in that way.  It comes through the Document>Settings>Modules dialogue.

Comment: Can you make a MWE? If not it might be hard to answer what is going on

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate?  What is a MWE?

Comment: @MarvinWardJr http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample . Note that .lyx files are just text files so you can post the file here as "code" by just opening the .lyx file, copying, and pasting in here.

Comment: I actually do not know what is causing this problem, so I am not sure how to wrap it in a standalone file.  All I can do is show you the difference between the two files.  Thanks for taking the time to check it out.

Comment: OP cross-posted here: https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg100878.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the problem.  Though I am not clear on why this happened, it appears that a number of my floats broke all at once.  I had them referenced as "float: Model" (a custom module), and at some point they all were redesignated to the blank float choice.  "float: model" appeared instead, but if you clicked on the float tag (the tab on the top left corner of each float) to change the float type, it wasn't selected as any of the available options.  This must have been creating that empty float definition in the front matter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The floats were `Table`s and I have inserted some code `Listing`s into the tables. Suddenly, the float's type was shown as `listing` but the real type of the float (as shown in the settings) became empty. Then I couldn't compile the document.

To fix this, I went to the float's settings and set the float type to `Table`. This needed to be done with all floats where I inserted code listings.

I believe this is a bug in LyX: when a `code listing` is inserted into a table cell, and when the table is part of a float, the entire float's type is cleared and becomes invalid.